# Cелектор *

Tags: html, css

```
*{padding:0;margin:0}
```

Вопрос плохой  работы касается только каких браузеров? Если ie6-ie7 не верстать, то может есть смысл использовать этот селектор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть смысл. Но в указанном примере лучше используйте [CSS RESET](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

Эта строка не связана с плохой работой браузера, это самый простой сброс отступов по умолчанию. Все браузеры имеют стили по умолчанию, как старые, так и современные, поэтому сбрасывать их нужно всегда и независимо от того, поддерживаете ли вы ие6/7 или верстаете строго под последний хром.

Comment: > сбрасывать их нужно всегда и независимо от того

Пользователь настраивал, настраивал, но тут пришел художник и сбросил.